# GraphViz - How To Draw These Edges

Tags: graphviz, diagram, image-graphviz

Heylo, I just wanted to see if edges like the ones I've mocked up in the image below (in blue/cyan) are possible... I've tried a lot of different combinations of edge attributes and I'm really struggling on getting the edges to look clean and organized and not taking the shortest path possible.

[image: Edge Example]

My code is as follows and I do not want the subgraphs to move from their current positions so I know a ‘constraint = false’ will be required for the edges.

```
digraph G
{
    graph [compound = true];
    splines = false;
    node [style = bold, shape = record, fontcolor = magenta];

    subgraph cluster0
    {
        style = bold; label = “Mac”;
        edge [style = invisible, arrowhead = none];
        “Finder” -> “Terminal” -> “Safari”;
    }

    subgraph cluster1
    {
         style = bold; label = “Windows”;
         node_1 [label = “<f0> Start|<f1> Command Prompt”];
    }

    subgraph cluster2
    {
         style = bold; label = “Linux”;
         node_2 [label = “<f0> Start|<f1> Konsole”];
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't see your picture

Comment: @vaettchen Sorry about that! It’s been fixed. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do exactly what you want. Graphviz is for drawing graphs. Strictly speaking, your diagram isn't a graph because the edge from `terminal` forks. You'd have to tweak until two actual edges happened to overlap exactly. You're probably using the wrong tool.  Consider using `tikz` or `pstricks` with LaTeX to lay out your diagram manually. Here are examples of what's possible: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/

Comment: Minor gripe: your code has smart quotes in it -- I had to replace those before `dot` would accept it.

Comment: There is another glitch - `node_1` is defined twice, in Windows and in Linux. Both the smartquotes and the redundant definition show that the code posted here was not tested.

Comment: @vaettchen Yes thank you. I have the code on my machine and just typed this example quickly to show what I was trying to do since running the code wasn’t absolutely essential to my question. My apologies.

Comment: @BartonChittenden I’ve never had a problem running these before, I apologize for the inconvenience. I learned ‘dot’ from SO and the getting started guide and many examples on SO used them.

Comment: But we want to copy and paste and get exactly the result that causes your problem, so presenting valid code is esssential. Never mind - I have played around quite a bit and don't think anything that comes close to what you want would be achievable with plain `graphviz`. One could start with empty nodes etc. but that would be lot o effort and still unsatisfactory.

Comment: @vaettchen I hear you, but this was more of a how to/is possible question, not a problem to replicate. It probably would have been better to just not include the code, but that’s no fun. :P Nonetheless, thanks for your help.

Comment: No issues and next time / always pls include (tested) code. We need to play around with something and give you something back that you can relate to, rather than giving hypothetical answers to theoretical questions. Enjoy graphviz!

Comment: @vaettchen Makes sense and I definitely will in the future. Unfortunately, it’s looking as though GraphViz is not the solution I’m looking for. Have a good night!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a *direct* answer, but [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#simple) sits on top of GraphVis and generates edges similar to what you're looking for -- so you may be able to generate the `.dot` file ( see the second example under [Conditional](http://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#conditional) ), inspect the edges there.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. :)